# HTTPS with Webscoket is not working in Blazemeter however works with Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, blazemeter

My script works fine in Jmeter. Script includes https and WSS. In Jmeter works fine for 750 users. Same I tried with the Blazemeter then it gives the error "Http upgrade failed with status code 400". I have upload all the related plugins as well as .csv file. Can anybody will help me?

Script is related to QUIZ. We have sets of questions and answers should be given in 10 seconds.

Blazemeter Error: 
Websocket open connection - Response code 400 - Http upgrade failed with status code 400

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) definition:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.
>
> ```
> The client should not repeat this request without modification.
> ```

Most probably the request originating from BlazeMeter gets corrupt somehow. It is impossible to say anything without seeing your Test Plan and BlazeMeter test configurations.

The only recommendations I can give right away are:

1. Check out [`Logs` tab](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733849-Logs-Report) of your test report and search for any suspicious entries.
2. Temporarily enable storing of request/response details by adding the next [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

   ```
    jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
    jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   ```

   alternatively you can do the same by adding a Listener like [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)
3. Reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support), they should be better aware of their infrastructure and possess more knowledge than anyone here